# Rust using variable without borrowing or cloning it in thread

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have a problem writing to files in actix web. When I want to write to files I need to place that in a thread, but then it is trying to clone files and is borrowing the form, which causes a lifetime error. How can I fix that. How can I use a variable within a thread without borrowing it.

```rs
for content in &form.files {
        let mut file = process_file(
            content.content_type.clone(),uuid.clone(),
        )?;
        web::block(move || file.write_all(&content.bytes))
            .await
            .map_err(ApiError::error)?
            .map_err(ApiError::error)?;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provide no actual reproduction case, no error message, and only a small part of the code, making investigation difficult as most SO readers are not psychic.

But I would assume the issue is this:

```rust
for content in &form.files {
```

`form.files` is probably something like a vec, meaning here `content` is already a borrow.

You need to move `content` out of the collection instead, assuming you cannot just move `form.files` itself, that means you need either some sort of draining iterator similar to [`Vec::drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain), or you need to manually pop the items out of the collection.